# Converting Mysql Timestamp to time since posted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql column with the following attributes

```
listDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT = CURRENT_TIME
```

and I am displaying it in my table like this

```
echo "<td>" . $row['listDate']  . "</td>";
```

How would one go about converting the output to time since posted instead of the default:

```
2014-12-17 00:32:50
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How would one go about converting the output to time` ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty "converting the output to time since posted" Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MySQL Query, you could use [TimeStampDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
SELECT 
    timestampdiff(MINUTE,listDate, NOW()) as minutes_from_list_date
FROM table_name
```

If you read the documentation, you should see a few ways on how you could change the output to what you might want/need.

to use it in your php code, you would call it like so:

```
echo '<td>'. $row['minutes_from_list_date'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Ive been looking around for a bit, but nothing that helps me change it right at `echo "<td>" . $row['listDate']  . "</td>";`

Comment: see the edit I made to the post above.

Comment: Thanks Got this to work by inserting it into my mysql statement

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php) class

```
$timePosted = new DateTime ($row['listdate']);
$timeNow = new DateTime("now");
$timeSince = $timePosted->diff($timeNow);

echo $timeSince->format("Since posted passed %a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a function **[timestampdiff()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)** and you can use it to generate the query something like below and its widely used in comment/reply section where it shows as
`1 year ago`, `10 days ago`, `2 hours ago`, `just now` etc

```
select 
case 
when timestampdiff(year,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) > 0 then concat(timestampdiff(year,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) ,' years ago') 
when timestampdiff(month,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) > 0 then concat(timestampdiff(month,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) ,' months ago') 
when timestampdiff(day,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) > 0 then concat(timestampdiff(day,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) ,' days ago') 
when timestampdiff(hour,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) > 0  then concat(timestampdiff(hour,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) ,' hours ago') 
when timestampdiff(minute,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()) > 0 then concat(timestampdiff(minute,'2014-12-17 10:10:24',now()),' minutes ago') 
else 'just now' 
end as posted ;
+-------------+
| posted      |
+-------------+
| 3 hours ago |
+-------------+
```

In the query you can change the hard-coded datetime value with your column name.

The logic is

- first it will check if the difference in terms of year is more than 0 then set the string `posted {diff in years} ago`
- else if it is months then set
- else if it is days then set
- else if it is hours then set
- else if it is in minute then set
- else set the string as just now