# How to get time elapsed in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

How to get time elapsed in mysql query?.Assume we have a datetime column,therefore the output should come like this.

in 30 secs ago
in 15 minutes ago
in 3 hours ago
in 2 days ago
in 3 months ago
in 125 years ago

this can be implement by using php,but if we do in mysql query ,it will be the perfect solution.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520384/converting-mysql-timestamp-to-time-since-posted/27520635#27520635

Comment: Please show a row or two of sample data and the result you hope to see.

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty you have saved my life....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that the date column in your table is called `datecol`

```
SELECT *, @sec=TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), datecol)),
  CASE
       WHEN @sec < 60 THEN CONCAT(@sec," seconds ago")
       WHEN @sec >= 60 AND @sec < 3600 THEN CONCAT(FLOOR(@sec/60)," minutes ago")
       WHEN @sec >= 3600 AND @sec < 86400 THEN CONCAT(FLOOR(@sec/86400)," hours ago")
       WHEN @sec >= 86400 AND @sec < 2592000 THEN CONCAT(FLOOR(@sec/2592000)," days ago")
       WHEN @sec >=2592000 AND @sec < 946080000 THEN CONCAT(FLOOR(@sec/946080000)," years ago")
  END AS elapsed

FROM table
```

However it may be a bit inaccurate because some months do not have 30 days, and some years do not have 365 days.